# nftables preventing services from resolving on IPv6

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, tcp, nftables

I've got my server set up with long list of services, and everything is working great... on IPv4.  But when I test them against IPv6 nothing is resolving.  After disabling `nftables` everything started working, so I turned it back on and through trial and error, was able to identify the two lines (identified with `-->` below) that were causing things to fail...

```
# Accept related or established, drop bad, accept everything else
add rule inet filter INPUT ct state related,established accept
add rule inet filter INPUT tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg) == 0x0 drop
--> add rule inet filter INPUT tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|ack) != syn ct state new drop
--> add rule inet filter INPUT tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg) == fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg drop
add rule inet filter INPUT iifname "lo" accept
```

I'm not as educated as I should be on TCP, actually I'm just educated enough to get myself into trouble, so I'd appreciate some help interpreting what I'm doing here.  My understanding is that I'm  accepting all related/established traffic, and all traffic related to the loopback interface.  I'm really just looking at "new" requests...

My problem is that I don't really understand the TCP flags other than `syn` and `ack` (and really only insofar as how they work in a *three way TLS handshake*), the others I've added here just seemed to be common in the tutorials I was reviewing.  My fear is I don't understand the implication of leaving them there, or taking them out and what I'm opening myself up to.  My goal is to allow IPv4 and IPv6 traffic, while eliminating any *bad* or *unrelated* packets from getting through.

This will eventually be tied to a commercial offering, so I'd like to understand better but need a little guidance.  Would appreciate anyone helping clear this up with me.

---

**EDIT:** Turns out these were not the issue, the rules that were causing the issue were actually the `icmp` rules, IPv6 requires a handful of `nb-*` rules in order to operate properly.  I'll provide details in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the rules I posted were not the culprit, as I've noted in the question update.  The actual issue was related to ICMP traffic and in particular several types related directly to IPv6.  My ICMP rules were...

```
add rule inet filter INPUT ct state new icmp type { echo-request, echo-reply } accept
add rule inet filter INPUT ct state new icmpv6 type { echo-request, echo-reply } accept
```

But in order to operate properly IPv6 requires a number of *Neighbour Discovery* related rules (`nd-*`). I've included them as well as a few other types that are all part of being a "good network citizen". The ones I thought were the issue were actually important for attack mitigation and are working fine now that I've fixed my ICMP traffic.

The new ICMP rules are...

```
add rule inet filter INPUT ip protocol icmp icmp type { destination-unreachable, echo-reply, echo-request, source-quench, time-exceeded } accept
add rule inet filter INPUT ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, echo-reply, echo-request, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-advert, packet-too-big, parameter-problem, time-exceeded } accept
```

The original rules I thought were the issue are actually for mitigating malicious behaviour...

**XMAS Attack** This rule is for mitigating the *XMAS attack*, or one that enables the packet bits for all tcp *types*, otherwise, lighting it up like a "Christmas tree" in order to parse the slight differences in OS responses to such a request to help identify further avenues of attack by a bad actor...

```
add rule inet filter INPUT tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg) == fin|syn|rst|psh|ack|urg drop
```

**Force SYN check** If I understand it right, this helps to lower the processing load by eliminating other useless packets that precede the initial SYN packet that could be part of an attack on resources, like a denial of service via resource exhaustion...

```
add rule inet filter INPUT tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|ack) != syn ct state new drop
```

[This post](https://xdeb.org/post/2019/09/26/setting-up-a-server-firewall-with-nftables-that-support-wireguard-vpn/) helped me get a foothold and start searching out a better understanding.

Hope this provides a shortcut to the answer for someone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to simplify your nftables rules. Here are mine which work:

```
table inet Filter {
        chain Input {
                type filter hook input priority 0
                policy drop
                iif lo accept

                ct state established,related counter accept
                ct state invalid counter drop

                #Your other rules here

                # this rule exists to avoid junk in syslog
                ct state new tcp flags & (fin|syn|rst|ack) != syn counter drop
        }
}
```

If you don't need `counter` you may remove it everywhere.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I'm not looking for simplicity as much as a better understanding.  This is a low resource machine and I want to suck every ounce of power out of it, but these rules are actually pretty important now that I've fully identified what they're doing. Turns out my issue wasn't related to these rules at all, and having dug a little deeper I'll provide a more detailed explanation in another answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your IP6 rules to be clobbered by your IP4 rules, then change "inet" to "ip".  nftables allows rules that apply to IP4 ("ip"), IP6 ("ip6") and for both IP4 and IP6 ("inet").  The intention is that TCP and UDP rules can be handled consistently in one place.  Features are later known as bugs.

Comment: This might be valid advice *in general,* or it might be a solution to some *other* problem.  But (1) It appears from the question that the OP has *only* `inet` rules.  So, where are IPv6 rules being “clobbered by” IPv4 rules?  Should they change ***all*** their IP rules to “`ip`”  (= IPv4, according to your answer), leaving ***no*** IPv6 rules?  (2) Did you notice that the OP answered their own question?  And that the answer had to do with ICMP, and not TCP or UDP? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … You might want to ask a new question, and then post the above as an answer to *that* question.

Comment: If the firewall has a default drop policy, IP6 needs specific rules not not block neighbour discovery, which is the equivalent of ARP in IP4.  You're welcome to suggest how to put these in the inet chain, but others have already done that.  If you don't know, then you will have to stick with might and maybe and perhaps answers.